# How to package appimage properly?

Tags: packaging, appimage

I am trying to package my application in `appimage` format. I'm using `appimage-builder` to do so, and using Ubuntu 18.04, as `appimage-builder` [documentation](https://appimage-builder.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) recommends. But I am unable to do so. I cloned my repository, and I ran `meson build -Dprefix=/usr`, then `DESTDIR=$PWD/AppDir ninja -C build install` then `appimage-builder --generate`, this did not add any dependency at all in the recipe, so I added them manually, then I run `appimage-builder`. My asset files fails to load using this method when testing on the machine the `appimage` is being generated on. As I am generating a `config.h` based on the prefix the user passes to `meson` and using those paths inside application to find asset files like icons and all. When the generation completes, all tests pass, while failing to load assets, which does not cause application to stop just gives a warning. But outside of this machine I cannot run this `appimage` anywhere, I get this error when running on a different machine,

```
**
Gtk:ERROR:../../../../gtk/gtkiconhelper.c:494:ensure_surface_for_gicon: assertion failed (error
== NULL): Failed to load /org/gtk/libgtk/icons/16x16/status/image-missing.png: Unrecognized image file format (gdk-pixbuf-error-quark, 3)
[appimage-binfmt-bypass/bin] ERROR: child exited with code 6
```

Here is a link to my project - [SampleHive](https://gitlab.com/samplehive/sample-hive)

If needed I can also share the generated recipe, including the things a I added manually.